# Looping double array from JSON using EJS Template Engine and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have the output like this, just focus to otherMeta array

```
{
  otherMeta: [
    {
      name: [
        "a1",
        "a2",
        "a3",
        "a4"
      ],
      content: [
        "c1",
        "c2",
        "c3",
        "c4"
      ]
    }
  ],
  title: 'Dashboard',
  session: session,
  page: 'dashboard'
}
```

And this for ejs file
`

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < otherMeta.name.length; i++) { %>
<meta name="<%= otherMeta.name[i] %>" content="<%= otherMeta.content[i] %>" />
<% } %>
```

`

But that doesn't work, have a solution?

Comment: otherMeta is an array that contains 1 element, an object.  so, `otherMeta[0].name.length` etc

Comment: The result is **Cannot read property '0' of undefined**

Comment: otherMeta is undefined, then.

Comment: the result if I print otherMeta is [object Object]